# Optimal way of repeating the same notification every day but in different time in ionic capacitor LocalNotification

Tags: capacitor, localnotification

I need to create notification every day but at different times, the content is all the same but the only difference is the timing. I am using LocalNotification of Ionic Capacitor. Can anyone tell me the optimal way to do this task?

Comment: good starting point: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/background-task